# What does "enough" and "too many" value mean in animation-name property?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm reading a book about CSS animation. I have found this sentence:

> Every listed animation-name should have a corresponding value for any
>   other animation-* properties. If there are too many values in an animation-* 
>   property, any leftover values are ignored. If there aren’t
>   enough values, the list of values will be repeated until there are
>   enough to match.

I can't figure out what is the story of too many or not enough corresponding value, maybe someone has an idea? any hint would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic example:

```
.too-many {
  animation-name: one, two;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s;
  /* the 2s, 3s and 4s will get ingored because they cannot be matched with any animation*/
}

.not-enough {
  animation-name: one, two, three, four, five, six, seven;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
  /*it's like having
   animation-delay: 0s, 1s, 0s, 1s, 0s, 1s, 0s;
   we repeat until we cover all the animations
  */
}
```

So basically if we have less values than the `animation-name` we repeat until we get the same number. If we have more we don't consider the *overflow*

---

Same logic apply to any properties that can take multiple values like `transition` and `background` for example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
     linear-gradient(red, red), 
     linear-gradient(blue, blue), 
     linear-gradient(red, red), 
     linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-size: 20px 20px, 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top, bottom, left, right;
}
```

The above is the same as this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
     linear-gradient(red, red), 
     linear-gradient(blue, blue), 
     linear-gradient(red, red), 
     linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-size: 20px 20px, 50px 50px,20px 20px, 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat;
  background-position: top, bottom, left, right;
}
```

You can keep adding more and they will get ignored:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
     linear-gradient(red, red), 
     linear-gradient(blue, blue), 
     linear-gradient(red, red), 
     linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-size: 20px 20px, 50px 50px,20px 20px, 50px 50px,54px 548px, 0 0, 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat,repeat,repeat,no-repeat;
  background-position: top, bottom, left, right,0 0,center, bottom left;
}
```

Comment: make also to `padding/margin`

Comment: @לבנימלכה not, it's not the same .. padding/margin is about shorthand. there is rules depending on how many values

Comment: oh... nice to know :)

Comment: @לבנימלכה also note the `,` separation between values. Padding/margin are separted with space. So this logic consider properties that can have multiple values (from 0 to infinity) like aniamtion, transition, background, etc

Comment: Oh... thanks about explaintion ..it is clear (almost as crystal ; ) ) Maybe add this (yours ) comment to answer